# digital calculator in Javascript and document.getElementsByClassName("DigitalCalculator")

Tags: javascript, clock, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to write a program for digital calculator.
My browser doesnt display any clock when I load the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.DigitalCalculator{
 background-color:blue;}

</style>        
</head>
<body>
<div **class="DigitalCalculator"**></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTimer(){

var time = new Date();
var h = time.getHours();
var m = time.getMinutes();
var s = time.getSeconds();
var setTime = ;
setTime.innerHTML = **document.getElementsByClassName("DigitalCalculator")**;
setTimeout('updateTimer()',1000);
        }
updateTimer();    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does this dont work? **document.getElementsByClassName("DigitalCalculator")** ?

I resolved the problem by changing the code

and 
var setTime = **document.getElementById("clockDisplay");**

Why cant I use the former **document.getElementsByClassName("DigitalCalculator")**  ?
Please see my below program.
    
    
    
    .DigitalCalculator{
     background-color:blue;}

```
</style>        
</head>
<body>
<div id = "DisplayClock" **class="DigitalCalculator"**></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTimer(){

var time = new Date();
var h = time.getHours();
var m = time.getMinutes();
var s = time.getSeconds();
var setTime =document.getElementById("DisplayClock");
setTime.innerHTML = h;
setTimeout('updateTimer()',1000);
        }
updateTimer();    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect that line to do?

Comment: Also, please try to post **valid** code - use comments when you want to point something out. It's hard to tell whether your first code sample is horribly broken (`var setTime = ;` etc.) or if the thing that's missing is on purpose.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array, not an HTML element. You'd need to use getElementsByClassName('className')[0] to access the first found element. As you discovered, using an ID instead of a class is easier

Comment: Also, the obligatory: have you looked at the error console in the developer tools?

Comment: Hi Hg3 :                                                            Thanks getElementsByClassName('className')[0]  worked.getElementsByClassName returns an array, not an HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your two versions:

```
// syntax error
var setTime = ;

// trying to set the innerHTML of ? to a list of elements
// makes no sense!
setTime.innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("DigitalCalculator");
```

versus:

```
// grab the div and keep it in a variable
var setTime =document.getElementById("DisplayClock");

// set the innerHTML of the div to the value of h (a number)
// now it makes sense...
setTime.innerHTML = h;
```

Also, I would recommend passing a function reference to `setTimeout`, instead of a string:

```
setTimeout(updateTimer, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the advantage of using getElementsById().  However, this returns an array, so you either have to reference the first hit (as per example below) or enumerate the returned instances and update each one.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.DigitalCalculator { background-color:blue; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="DigitalCalculator"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTimer(){

var time = new Date();
var h = time.getHours();
var m = time.getMinutes();
var s = time.getSeconds();
var setTime = null;
setTime = document.getElementsByClassName('DigitalCalculator');
if ( setTime != null ) {
    setTime[0].innerHTML = h.toString() + ':' + m.toString() + ':' + s.toString();
    }
setTimeout('updateTimer()',1000);
}

updateTimer();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```